# Creating a vulnerable Django search bar

Tags: django, sql-injection

I want to create a vulnerable search bar and have done everything but unfortunately, the search function doesn't show any result when I press submit. 
But terminal shows successful, "POST /injection/ HTTP/1.1" 200 596

```
views.py
    @csrf_exempt
    def search_form(request):
        if 'searchField' in request.POST:
            query= "SELECT * FROM injection_search WHERE injection_search.name LIKE '%searchField%'"
            print(query)
            item = search.objects.raw(query)

        else:
            item = search.objects.all()     
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'item' : item})

template/home.html

{% load static %} 
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<h1 class="page-header">INJECTION</h1>

<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="searchField" id="searchField" placeholder="search trainers..">
<button  type="submit">Find</button>
</form>

<h1> Search Page </h1>
<h3> Injection demo</h3>
<div class="shopping-container">

    <table border="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
           </tr>
           <!--{% for search in item %}-->
           <tr>
            <td>{{ search.name}}</td>
            <td>{{ search.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ search.price}}</td>
          </tr>
          <!--{%endfor%}-->
  </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

model.py
app_name = 'injection'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^injection/$', views.search_form, name='search_form'),
]
```

Comment: You don't ever pass the posted value into the SQL.

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain that a little bit for me? Thanks in advance

Comment: my searchField represents my search field, so I think I'm posting here but I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes but your SQL string just contains the literal value "searchField",  it didn't use the value of the searchField variable.

Comment: I have the same query for php and it works but really I don't know why it shouldn't work here. Can you please kindly show me how can I implement it or pass the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wouldn't work on PHP either, because you are **not using your variable** in your SQL string. You are simply using the literal value "searchField".

In order for your code to work you actually need to put the value of the string into your SQL command. In Python there are multiple ways of doing this, one example would be:

```
query= "SELECT * FROM injection_search WHERE injection_search.name LIKE '%{}%'".format(searchField)
```